# Appcelerator - config.adapter.idAttribute "id" not found in list of colums for table iOS 11

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, ios11

I'm at my wits end. I have an Appcelerator application for iOS and Android. It uses Alloy models. And i can't get this to work on iOS 11.

When building and launching the app in the iPhone 7 Simulator in iOS 11 I get the following error when the app starts up.

```
[DEBUG] :  Installing sql database "db.sql" with name "db"
[INFO] :   [LiveView] Error Evaluating /alloy/models/Receive.js @ Line: <null>
[ERROR] :  config.adapter.idAttribute "id" not found in list of columns for table "receive"
[ERROR] :  columns: []
[ERROR] :  File: /alloy/models/Receive.js
[ERROR] :  Line: <null>
[ERROR] :  SourceId: <null>
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :   undefined
[INFO] :   [LiveView] Error Evaluating app.js @ Line: 240
[ERROR] :  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new (require("/alloy/models/" + ucfirst(name)).Collection)(args)')
[ERROR] :  File: app.js
[ERROR] :  Line: 240
[ERROR] :  SourceId: <null>
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :   undefined
[DEBUG] :  Application booted in 835.013032 ms
[TRACE] :  Uploaded tiapp metadata with Appcelerator Platform!
```

This only happens in iOS 11. Building for iOS 10.3 and Android works fine, and the app works perfectly.

My models/receive.js looks like this.

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        "columns": {
            "id"            : "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
            "lev_naam"        : "TEXT",
            "product"        : "TEXT",
            "state"            : "INTEGER",
            "type"            : "TEXT",
            "subtype"        : "TEXT",
            "temp"            : "TEXT",
            "packing"        : "INTEGER",
            "freshness"        : "INTEGER",
            "tht"            : "INTEGER",
            "description"    : "TEXT",
            "check_date"    : "INTEGER",
            "check_week"    : "INTEGER",
            "check_year"    : "INTEGER",
            "creation_date"    : "INTEGER",
            "update_date"    : "INTEGER",
            "username"        : "TEXT",
            "location"        : "TEXT",
            "db_id"            : "INTEGER",
            "issend"        : "INTEGER",
            "isdeleted"        : "INTEGER",
            "uid"            : "TEXT",
        },
        "defaults": {
            "lev_naam"        : "",
            "product"        : "",
            "state"            : -1,
            "type"            : "",
            "subtype"        : "",
            "temp"            : null,
            "packing"        : null,
            "freshness"        : null,
            "tht"            : null,
            "description"    : "",
            "check_date"    : null,
            "check_week"    : null,
            "check_year"    : null,
            "creation_date"    : 0,
            "update_date"    : 0, 
            "username"        : null,
            "isdeleted"        : null,
            "issend"        : null,
            "db_id"            : null,
            "uid"            : null,
        },        
        "adapter": {
            "db_file"         : 'db.sql',
            "type": "sql",
            "collection_name": "receive",
            "idAttribute": "id",
        }
    },
(.... rest of code)
```

When I remove the idAttribute key in the adapter object for all my models it build and runs in iOS 11, but my fetch queries fail for some reason, because i'm fetching items with their id.

I'm using the latest version of Appcelerator and I've updated the Titanium SDK to latest (6.2.2.GA).

The error is telling my that somehow the applications sees my column object as empty.... But it obviously isn't.

Hope you guys have the answer!

Comment: why would you want to remove the `idAttribute` property?

Comment: If you don't specify it it will default to `alloy_id`

Comment: I know, but i need the id to be the idAttribute; but with that set my app won't start in iOS 11....